# Matching specific items in several discrete collections

Tags: collections, vb6, matching, list-manipulation

I have a problem whereby I have several discrete lists of ID's eg.

List (A) 1,2,3,4,5,7,8
List (B) 2,3,4,5
List (C) 4,2,8,9,1
etc...

I then have another collection of ID's...
For example: 1,2,4

I need to try and match one into each list. If I can perfectly match all ID's in my secondary collection (one collection ID matched with an ID from each list) then I get a true result....

I have found that it becomes complicated because if you simply iterate over the lists matching the first collection/list pair that you encounter it may result in you precluding a possible combination further on down the line hence returning a false negative result.

For example:

List (A) 1,2,3,4
List (B) 1,2,3,4
List (C) 3,4

Collection is: 3,1,2

The first ID from the collection (3) matches with an entry in list A, the second ID in the collection (1) matches an item in list B, however the final ID in the collection (2) DOESNT match any entry in list C however if you rearrange the order of the collection to be: 2,1,3 then a match is found.... Therefore I am looking for some form of logic for attempting a match on all possible combinations in an efficient manner(?)

To make it more complicated the ID's are actually GUID's so cant just be sorted in ascending order

I hope I have described this well enough to make it clear what I am attempting and with a bit of luck somebody will be able to tell me that what I need to do is very easy and I am missing something real simple!
I am forced to code this in VB6 but any methods or pseudo code would be great. The backend of this is SQL server so if a solution using TSQL was possible this would be even better as all of the ID's are held in tables already.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So, do the lists also contain GUID's? Once a match is found in a list, is that list removed from further checks?

Answer (score 0):

Jake, yep the lists and the collection both contain GUIDS. I used plain integers to simplify the problem a bit.

Once a list has been matched it cant be searched again, hence the ordering problem that I tried to explain. If you say that a list as 'matched' then no further attempts to match this will be performed. It is this very behaviour that can cause a false negative.

'Sending' the collection in in every possible combination of orders would work but would be a massive job .....

I feel I must be missing a really straightforward concept or solution here??!!
Thanks for your assistance so far.

Comment: Merge the lists and search in the merged list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way around checking each GUID contained in the lists against each GUID in the collection. You would have to keep record of in which lists each GUID in the collection occurs.

To use your example of the Collection (3, 1, 2), 3 occurs in List A, B and C.
You will basically be left with this dataset.

- 3 (A, B, C)
- 1 (A, B)
- 2 (A, B)

Once you have distilled it down to this dataset you can determine whether there are any GUIDs with zero occurrences in the lists which would result in a negative.

I am not at all well versed in algorithms, but this is how I would proceed after that :
Start with the first set (A, B, C), and check how many times it occurs further on in the dataset. In this case no occurrences are found.

Moving on to the next set (A, B), if the number of occurrences of this set is found to be greater than the length of this set, i.e. more than two occurrences, would result in a negative. If the number of occurrences match the length exactly, as is the case here, the set (A, B) can be removed from any further consideration.

- 3 (C)
- 1 ()
- 2 ()

I guess you would continue to repeat the process until a negative is identified or all the occurrences have been excluded. There is probably a recognized algorithm for this sort of problem, but my knowledge is a bit lacking in that respect. :(